# SSRS Format Number Separator

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a field in SSRS that returns the value of numbers varying from ## to #######. I want these numbers to be separated by thousands. I have seen a few posts saying you could use this:

```
=Format(Fields!Number.Value,"#,#.##")
```

However, I have this textbox to display data from a different dataset, like:

```
=First(Fields!Price.Value, "DataSet3")
```

Now, the question is how do I combine both? Is it possible to wrap it like this:

```
=Format(First(Fields!Price.Value, "DataSet3"),"#,#.##")
```

If I do this and run the report then the output on the text field is just **#,#.##** and not the actual number itself.

Input: 100000000
Output that I expect: 100,000,000
Output that I get: #,#.##

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why dont you put the format in the format property of the textblock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely some weird functionality. I didn't figure out exactly what was causing it, but I found that adding a datatype cast to the expression resolved the issue.

```
=FORMAT(CDec(First(Fields!XYZColumn.Value, "ZYXTable")), "#,#.##")
```